# Delete multiple lines in file (Nagios configuration)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, nagios

I tried to delete multiple lines from a Nagios configuration file. But I failed many times. Now I ask you for help.

Nagios configuration file:

```
define host{
        use                     linux-host
        host_name               vm1
        alias                   vm1
        address                 1.2.3.4    }

define host{
        use                     linux-host
        host_name               vm2
        alias                   vm2
        address                 1.2.3.4
}

define host{
        use                     linux-host
        host_name               vm3
        alias                   vm3
        address                 1.2.3.4
}
```

I need a general command which allows me to delete the whole text block (define host{.*}). E.g. for "vm2". The text blocks for vm1 and vm3 shouldn't be deleted.

Do you have an idea to do it?

Thank you in advance.
Tzzaetaynzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if blocks are separated by empty line and there is no empty line within block:

```
awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" '!/vm2/' file
```

**Note** that I used `vm2` as a pattern, you can refine it for your needs. For example: `host_name +vm1` or whatever.

Comment: It works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`-0777` read whole file (undef record separator)
`-i` inplace modification, 
`.BAK` to make a backup of file with extension .BAK

```
perl -0777 -i.BAK -pe 's/define host\{[^{]*vm2.*?\}//gs' config_file
```

Comment: Thank you for you fast reply.